# How to close a tkinter window automatically without time delay?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm setting up a new server to send button commands and print messages on the tkinter window.When ı press the button,the message 'A' will be printed on tkinter window,when ı release the button,message 'B' will  be printed until ı press the button again.I want the messages to change continouslyon tkinter window but ı dont know how to keep the tkinter window on screen as long as the button is pressed.Can you help me about that?

```
import socket as s
import RPI.GPIO as GPIO
import Tkinter
port=9225
host=127.1.1.0
soket=s.socket(s.AD_INET,s.SOCK_STREAM)
GPIO.setmode(..)
GPIO.setup(..)
soket.connect(host,port)
signal low=bool(0)
signalhigh=bool(1)
while True:
   if signallow:
       if GPIO.input()==GPIO.HIGH:
           output='1'
           soket.sendall(output.encode('utf-8'))
           print(output)
           window=Tkinter.TK()
           laebel=Tkinter.Label(text='A')
           laebel.pack()
           laebel.mainloop()
        #ı should write a code here probably
           signallow=0;
           signahigh=1;
  if signalhigh:
       if GPIO.input()==GPIO.LOW
           output=0
           soket.sendall(output.encode('utf-8'))
           print(output)
           laebel=Tkinter.Label(text='B')
           laebel.pack()
           laebel.mainloop()
  #ı should write a code here probably
           signallow=1;
           signalhigh=0;
```